# Elasticsearch Best Shard Count

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

I have a cluster with 2.3TB of data. The data is constantly accessed/has data removed/added.

Currently the infrastructure is being strained, so i'm looking into optimization. 100 shards is way too much.

I see answers that 30GB per shard should be max, then i hear about "You should only have 3 shards per node". I'm currently on 4 nodes. This can be bumped up.

So should i continue with 100 Shards (this makes each shard 20-25GB) or should i shrink index down to 12 Shards (3 shards x 4 nodes)?

What is the best practice in this case? To maintain speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that shards and replicas play a very important role in search and indexing and overall performance of Elasticsearch, but you are missing some important concepts, which are covered in detail in [opster's shard and replica guide](https://opster.com/blogs/elasticsearch-shards-and-replicas-getting-started-guide).

That should help to determine the root cause and will give you insights on how to improve performance of your Elasticsearch cluster.

Also, your statement **You should only have 3 shards per node is not correct** and both best practice is to have a shard size b/w 30-50 GB and the number of shards in a node depends on the JVM of Elasticsearch process and its size and your use case.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what i was looking for :) Appreciate it! Sorry for late marking of answer.

Comment: @ilovejq no issues, glad it was useful to you :)